# Inherit main requirements

Tags: django, pip

If I have 2 requirements for my django app, for example:

main.txt --> Django1.5, PIL, ....
local.txt --> debug_toolbar, ....

How can I inherit main.txt requirements in my local.text?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**local.txt**

```
-r main.txt

#list of requirements
```